# how can I keep song playing in reactjs even if I go to another page(of same website)

Tags: reactjs

1. list of albums are shown to the user.
2. User clicks on the album and sees a list of songs associated with that album.
3. User plays song and song is played but as soon as I go to another page song gets paused.

What I want to do After the 3rd step is I want the bottom music navbar to show the song name and playing status - play/pause.

Also when I play the song and move to another component the song gets paused so to keep playing song when i change the page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Have you a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you've an issue with? If so, please update your question to include this.

Comment: Also, is this a react or react native question? You tagged RN but your question title says website.

Comment: yes, its reactjs website, and I have code but I am looking from scratch, because that code is of no use and makes app heavy and I know that's not the good ideal code that's why did not shared , I am looking from scratch.

Comment: Please share the code you are trying to use or work with. SO isn't a code writing service. If I had to make a suggestion it would be to move the player component higher up in the React tree such that changing routes leaves it (the player) mounted.

Comment: hello @DrewReese  sir, thank you for helping and guiding me, there are many files i have created and that's why making no sense to me now, and so the reason I am looking from scratch , and the very main thing sir i want to do is when i am on page1.js or page2.js , and there are list of songs on page so if user plays any song from those respective pages ho do i updated that playing status and new song in bottom music navbar , thank you sir for your help.

Comment: You need only provide the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue. If we can fix that then you can take the knowledge gained and hopefully apply it against your *actual* code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `music component` in your root level (or so called as a parent component) and set all other path(routing) in the child components. So While browsing to another page it only render the `child components`, so your `parent component` remains same.

Here is the sample starter code that you're looking for:

```js
// index.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from "./layout"

ReactDOM.render(
  <Layout />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
// layout.jsx
import { useState, useCallback } from "react"
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import MusicPlayer from "./musicPlayer";
import MusicList from "./musicList";

const Layout = () => {
    const [currentPlaying, setCurrentPlaying] = useState(0)

    const updateMusic = (state) => {
        setCurrentPlaying(state)
    }
    const updateMusicCallback = useCallback(updateMusic, []);
    return (
        <>
            <MusicPlayer currentPlaying={currentPlaying} />
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<MusicList updateMusic={updateMusicCallback} />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Here you can see there is a music component which is places outside of `BrowseRouter` component. So That music Component will not re-render on change of route.

```js
// musicList.jsx

import React from "react"

const MusicList = React.memo(props => {
    return (
        <main style={{ padding: "1rem 0" }}>
            {Array(5).fill(1).map((music, i) => (
                <li style={{ listStyleType: "none" }} key={i}>{music.name} <button onClick={() => props.updateMusic(i + 1)}>Music {i + 1}</button></li>
            ))}
        </main>
    );
})

export default MusicList
```

```js
// musicPlayer.jsx

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

const MusicPlayer = ({ currentPlaying }) => {
    const musicBaseUrl = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-"
    const [musicSrc, setMusicSrc] = useState(`${musicBaseUrl}1.mp3`)
    const audioRef = useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
        audioRef.current.load();
        audioRef.current.play();
        setMusicSrc(`${musicBaseUrl}${currentPlaying}.mp3`)
    }, [currentPlaying])
    return (
        <>
            <audio controls autoPlay ref={audioRef} >
                <source src={musicSrc} type="audio/ogg" />
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </>
    )
}

export default MusicPlayer
```

This will be helpful for you. You can comment it out if you have something to discuss.

Comment: nice approach brother but this is what i tried and issue was how do i updated that status of parent component like when someone clicks on one of song form song list given in page1.jsx or page2.jsx ? I am very beginner brother pardon me if i am wrong just want to implement something like i asked in question , btw i appreciated your answer and +1 for that @Pradip Dhakal

Comment: Hi @LiveCoder, I've update code accordingly, please check it, and let me know. And if you think, this is what you need, please accept my answer. Thank you!

Comment: hey there @pradipdhakal brother , it worked and working amazingly but i will be needing some more help from you in this case, is there any way using which i can connect to you brother please ? thanks a lot

Comment: you can connect me through my personal website https://dhakalpradip.com.np. Thank you.

Comment: brother please check your email.

Answer (score 1):

Try using component in app.js just like header, and keep music details inside that component which will not then rendered every time you change the component, I know not the perfect answer but may help.

```
// I am suggesting something like this.

<Router>
      your list of paths here...

     <BottomNavForPlayer />
</Router>
```

Answer (score -1):

Move music player component outside the `<Routes><Routes>`.